# how to stop re-rendering every time a state changes in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-storage

im fetching images from firebase Storage but every time any state changes here is the code :

```
const getImage = (name) => getDownloadURL(ref(storage, name));

  function PostImage({ image, alt }) {
    const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        setImageSrc(await getImage(image));
      })();
    }, [image]);

    return imageSrc ? (
      <img src={imageSrc} className="sm:w-1/2 w-full rounded-lg" alt={alt} />
    ) : null;
  }
```

I can't wrap it in a useEffect since it will only limit its scope so a cant call the function out side the useEffect, what can I do to only render the image on page load?

any help is appreciated , Thanks

Comment: I'm not too clear on what your problem is. React will re-render your component if your component's state changes, or your component's parent state changes. You can memoize your compnent with `React.memo()` if you want to stop that so that your component only rerenders when its props change when the parent rerenders.

Comment: every time im changing any state in the page the images is re rendering ,even tho it didn't change the image it self

Comment: the dependency array should be empty if you only want useEffect's callback to fire once

Comment: already tried that, but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct you - the code below says this  :

> execute this effect every time the value of `image` changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        setImageSrc(await getImage(image));
      })();
    }, [image]);
```

then in the effect you're updating the value of image. Hence the value of `image` will change. Since the value of `image` is changed , the `effect` will be executed again and the cycle will continue till infinity.

This is the `anti-pattern`.

If you want to fetch the images only once then :

```
useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        setImageSrc(await getImage(image));
      })();
    }, []);
```

Read more about [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: i tried that but its still giving the same issue

Comment: @MASTERKOURANI add codesandbox or stackblitz